# DNS is deleted from the resolv.conf file on Ubuntu

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

When restarting Ubuntu the static DNS configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf`disappears.

See this [article](https://itsfoss.com/resolvconf-permanent-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't manually edit /etc/resolv.conf.

What you do is go to the `network` icon in the top panel and select `Edit Connections...`, open the profile for your connection, and go to the IPv4 Settings tab and set it as follows:

- Automatic (DHCP) addresses only
- comma-separated list of DNS servers

[image]